# Looking for an application that will provide image matches on local machine

Tags: software, file-management, photo-management

I've found a bunch of programs that will spit out a list of duplicate images. In other words, you click "Go" and it looks at everything on a drive, or in a folder, and tells you if there are any duplicates. I'm looking for an application that will let me identify a specific image and search for matches to that image. In other words, I'm looking for the functionality of TinEye, but in a package that will search my local machine or network.

EDIT: I started my search in the other thread listed. Those are the applications that appear to be meant to find duplicate images, presumably so they can be erased to free to disc space. I could use that for what I'm trying to do, but with tens of thousands of images it would mean turning a task that should take a few seconds into one that takes a few hours. What I'm looking to do is select a single image and find other instances of that single image, on my C: drive or network. If anybody knows those other programs and thinks I've missed the boat on them, please point me in the right direction.

Any ideas?

Comment: We have several questions along this line already. How, software recommendations are not really a good fit for this site. Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com?

Comment: XnView is another option.

Comment: Pinhollow - I'm looking at XnView right now. It looks like a capable program, but I can't identify a function that will let me choose an image and then search for matches. Can you point me in the right direction, say, a menu?

Comment: It seems like the tags could be improved here. If "network" is the only applicable tag this question probably doesn't belong here.

Comment: I agree on the tags. I originally tagged it with all sorts of things that I thought would be useful, but the system told me that I couldn't use those tags until I had reached some seniority level that I lack, being a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Dup Detector](https://www.keronsoft.com/dupdetector.html)?
It's free, and other than finding duplicate images, you should be able to compare a single image to your image library.

[image]